# Showing and Hiding divs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('id + x').innerText = '[-]';
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('id + x').innerText = '[+]';
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(httpserver);" id="httpserverx">[+]</a>
<div id="httpserver" style="display:block;">
....my content...
</div>
```

When I click the + nothing happens.  I will eventually have multiple divs, each specifically named, so this function needs to be able to handle all the divs.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you wanting to happen when [+] is clicked?

Comment: try `toggle_visibility('httpserver')`

Comment: and document.getElementById(id + 'x')

Comment: @Matt - he wants to hide the <div>, not the <a>

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery and [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to change your HTML. You have to add `""` when you pass the value.

Change

`onclick="toggle_visibility(httpserver);"`

to

`onclick="toggle_visibility('httpserver');"`

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('httpserver');" id="httpserverx">[+]</a>
<div id="httpserver" style="display:none;">
....my content...
</div>
```

And then change

`document.getElementById('id + x').innerText`

to

`document.getElementById(id + 'x').innerText`

You should pass the `var id` appended with the `char x` but you pass the `id+x` as a char

JS:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById(id + 'x').innerText = '[-]';
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(id + 'x').innerText = '[+]';
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LnDUR/1)

Comment: You should also note that you need to quote httpserver  `toggle_visiblity("httpserver")`

Comment: This along with "try toggle_visibility('httpserver')" worked!!

Comment: I actually just noticed the [+] doesn't change to [-].  Any ideas?

Comment: @Darkmatter5 yes check here http://jsfiddle.net/LnDUR/1/ You have to start with `display:none` in your HTML

Comment: Yep I'm starting with display:none, but the [+] doesn't change.  It doesn't seem to change in the example you provided either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

First you need to change markup with following

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('httpserver');" // Wrap id with ''
```

As there was some quotes error in js too look for the comments in the below:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById(id + 'x').innerText = '[-]'; // Miss placed quotes ' with id and x
        e.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id + 'x').innerText = '[+]'; // Miss placed quotes ' with id and x
        e.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ97e/)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in a more concise and easier fashion using CSS and simply toggling a class via JS. Css content can swap out the + or - as well as show/hide the relevant contents.

```
.collapsible .toggle:before { content: '[+]' }
.collapsible.opened .toggle:before { content: '[-]' }
.collapsible .contents { display: none }
.collapsible.opened .contents { display: block }

$('.collapsible').on('click','.toggle',function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('opened'); 
});

<section class="collapsible"><a class="toggle" data-contents="part1">Part1</a><div class="contents" id="contents-part1">This is the expand/collapse content.</div></section>
<section class="collapsible"><a class="toggle" data-contents="part2">Part2</a><div class="contents" id="contents-part2">This is the expand/collapse content.</div></section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YG3kK/